# How to setup table A in such way, that a only one row from table B with a certain value can have foreign key relation to a row from table A?

Tags: sql, database

We have table A. Table B has foreign key to A. And now, if there is already a row in table B with attribute surname="Jordan" that has foreign key relation to a particular row in A , it will be impossible to create another row in table B with **the same** surname that will have relation with the same row in A.
How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on Table B's foreign key column.

Note that this suggests Table B should probably be folded into Table A.